# Template string in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I got the following code:

```
export default function CancelledPayment() {

  const linkPage = <Link to="/dashboard/payment" className={clsx(classes.paymentLinkTypography, classes.link)}> here </Link>;

  return (
    <Container>
      <Paper >
        <Paper />
        <Typography>
          {` To go back to your order please click ${linkPage}.You will be redirect in ${count} seconds.`}
        </Typography>
      </Paper>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Any idea why is it returning linkPage as [object Object]? The counter is correct, everything is working fine just this linkPage is not okay. If I took it out like:

```
To go back to your order please click {linkPage}. {`You will be redirect in ${count} seconds.`}
```

it is working fine, also in some other cases, but I would like everything to be in one line, using template string.

Comment: Cause you are passing an object :) What does the constant `linkPage` consist of? I can give you the answer or help you get to it yourself lol. Which one would you like?

Comment: Why are you trying to shoehorn this into a template literal in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

javascript is calling toString for any variable you're passing in the template string. And for any object calling toString will return [object Object] as value.

In your case what you want is something like:

```
<Typography>
  {'To go back to your order please click'}
  {linkPage}
  {`linkPage.You will be redirect in ${count} seconds.`}
</Typography>
```

Answer (score 5):

Template strings are a tool to create **strings**.

JSX is a tool to generate DOM(ish) objects.

When you force an object into a string you get `"[object Object]"` and not some JSX source code.

Don't use a template string for this. JSX is all you need.

```
    <Typography>
      To go back to your order please click {linkPage}.
     You will be redirect in {count} seconds.
    </Typography>
```

Comment: What i do not like is the eslint, is correcting it like this:                                                           ``` To go back to your order please click
          {' '}
          {linkPage}
          .
          You will be redirect to payment page in
          {' '}
          {count}
          {' '}
          seconds.                                                                                                                          ```

Comment: It's how it forces spaces between text nodes. Don't worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

Template strings are only for plain string interpolation with JavaScript. They always evaluate to a *string*. In contrast, using JSX to render React children allows for the interpolation of React elements.

You get `[object Object]` because

```
` To go back to your order please click ${linkPage}.
```

`linkPage` is a React child, which is a plain object - when coerced to a string, `[object Object]` is the result. Template literals always evaluate to strings, nothing else - they can't store React children.

So, you need something like:

```
<Typography>
{
    'To go back to your order please click'
    {linkPage}
    '. You will be redirected in'
    {count}
    'seconds.'
}
</Typography>
```

Comment: ` Line 85:16:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "}"

  83 |         <Typography className={classes.cancelledOrderTypography}> Order Cancelled</Typography>
  84 |         <Typography className={classes.paymentLinkTypography}>
> 85 |           { To go back to your order please click {linkPage} .You will be redirect to payment page in {count} seconds. }
     |                ^
  86 |         </Typography>
  87 |       </Paper>`